# Failed to start Bluetooth service

Tags: linux, debian, bluetooth

I installed Debian testing and added the required bluetooth firmware.

Looks like the firmware is working, but the Bluetooth service is failing to start with the following error.

```
systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
systemd[5839]: bluetooth.service: Failed to set up mount namespacing: /run/systemd/unit-root/var/lib/bluetooth: No such file or directory
systemd[5839]: bluetooth.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd: No such file or directory
systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE
systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start Bluetooth service.
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's the same problem that I had, you need to run the following:

```
sudo install -dm700 /var/lib/bluetooth
```

Then try starting the bluetooth service again.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it :)